# sweetalert2 ajax send otp code and get json response php

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, sweetalert

I want to send the otp code in ajax form with [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). Everything is fine and ajax is sent and the response is received. But the response it receives is **json** and I cannot process and display it in sweetalert2.

I used the following ways and did not get an answer:

For example from: response.json()

```
.then(response => {
   return response.json();
 })
```

For example from:

```
dataType: "JSON",
```

I put my code below for you.
Please tell me how to get the response returned from Ajax in the form of json and display it like the normal way we get json like this in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: ajax_url,
    data: {
        'action': actionName, 
    },
    success: function (response) { 
      if (data.response=== true) {
         alert('no access');
      }
                 
    }
});
```

I use the above code normally, but I don't want to use it in sweetalert2.
I want to use the following code:
`This is exactly my code that doesn't work:`

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Submit your number for get opt code',
    input: 'text',
    inputAttributes: {
        autocapitalize: 'off'
    },
    showCancelButton: true,
    inputValue: '0998',
    confirmButtonText: 'send opt code',
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    preConfirm: function () {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //  dataType: "JSON",     not workin  I checked it didn't work
            url: aw_ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action': 'aw_confirm_user_ajax_in_account',
            }

        }).then(response => {
           // return response.json();    not workin  I checked it didn't work

            return response;  // return json    This json code must be converted
        }).catch(error => {
            //   console.log(error); 
        });

    },
    allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        console.log(result); // get json and show value json
        // The problem here is that it is not possible to get json and display each unit of it.
    }
});
```

wordpress php code for process Ajax and return json code :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_aw_confirm_user_ajax_in_account',  'aw_confirm_user_ajax_in_account');

function aw_confirm_user_ajax_in_account()
{
   echo json_encode(array(
       'success' => true,
       'message' => 'send in',
       'loogin' => true,
   ));
   die;
}
```

The json code that shows the return response:

[image]

Please help me because I did not find a useful source that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get your values ​​using the name of each value in json `result.value['name']`.
Pay attention to my code please

```
Swal.fire({
            title: 'Submit your Github username',
            input: 'text',
            inputAttributes: {
                autocapitalize: 'off'
            },
            showCancelButton: true,
            inputValue: resolve,
            confirmButtonText: 'Look up',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: function () {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    //   dataType: "JSON",
                    url: aw_ajax.aw_ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        'action': 'aw_confirm_user_ajax_in_account',
                        'securityconfirn': aw_ajax.aw_nonce_referer,
                        'numberconfirm': resolve,
                    }

                }).then(response => {
                  //  aw_ajax_confirm_optCode(response);
                  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                  // console.log(obj['number']);
                  // console.log(response);
                    return obj;
                }).catch(error => {
                    //   console.log(error); // Nice to view which properties 'error' has
                })

            },
            allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
        }).then((result) => {
            if (1) {
             console.log(result);
             console.log( result.value);
              Swal.fire({
                  title :result.value['number'],
                  text :result.value['message'],
              });
            }
        });
```

Comment: hey @morteza-barati.Thank you, your code solved my problem.With the `JSON.parse(response)` function, I was able to decode the **JSON**. Thank you for helping me